# Format names in red,in one column if values in their row is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a way of highlighting a name if the person does not have a competency check or spot check done.

I have Column A and B with first and last name (its ok if just the first name is highlights)

And columns c to k have headings like 1st competency, 2nd competency, 3rd competency, etc.

Each person should have had at least 1 competency, so if the row is black next to their name , I want their name to appear red.

I have tried:

```
=AND(LEN(C1)*LEN(D1)*LEN(E1)*LEN(F1)*LEN(G1)*LEN(H1)*LEN(I1)*LEN(J1)*LEN(K1)=0,NOT(ISBLANK(A1)))
```

but its not working,

Any suggestions? Also what should I highlight: the cell, the column, or the whole sheet?

Please help!

Thank you guys

Comment: Are the competencies entered with 1 & 0 or Yes & No, if 1 & 0 then do a sum and test to be >0...

Comment: There is a date entered of when it was done

Comment: You should be accepting one of the answers...

Comment: both formulas worked perfectly thank you, I used JvdV's one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on:

> Format names in red,in one column if values in their row is **blank**

**1)** Select column A:B (or just A if you stick to one column)

**2)** Conditional formatting > New rule > Based on formula

**3)** Use formula: `=COUNTA($C1:$K1)=0`

**4)** Apply your formatting

[image]

Comment: thank you , worked perfectly, I changed the format to cell fill red and its great.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=AND($A1<>"",SUMPRODUCT(($C1:$K1<>"")*1)=0)
```

This gives `TRUE` for the conditions you have mentioned. Copy this into conditional formating for the desired cells. You can the edit the range you want it applied to.

JvdV's formula is sufficient, if you just want the letters to be colored. My formula based on your suggestion would be necessary if you want the cells colored.